# calculating percentages for multiple columns in one query

Tags: mysql

Hi I have my results in mySQL as shown below. I would like to calculate the % of the total for each column. How can I do multiple calculations in one query. I can do it individually but not as as group. Please help.

> ```
> Type  A   B   C
> 606   2034    150 1884
> 607   2025    158 1867
> 608   10118   713 9405
> ```

Comment: can you show how you do it individually ?

Comment: What is the domain? 2034+150+1884 or 2034+2025+10118 or 2034+150+1884+2025+158+1867+10118+713+9405 ?

Comment: Total of what? What should be the result? Each value by the total of the specific column ? Or?...

Comment: do you mean A =[14%,14%, 71%]

Comment: `SELECT Type1,
  COUNT(`X`) AS A,
  SUM(`Y`) AS B,
  (COUNT(`Y`) - SUM(`Y`)) AS C,
FROM table_Z
GROUP BY Type1`

Comment: I am trying to get the % of Y as the total of X

Comment: SELECT (SELECT @A:= COUNT(`X`)
  FROM table_Z) AS A

Answer (score 0):

First you can try this query :

```
   select Type,table.A,(table.A/A_sum)*100,table.B,(table.B/B_sum)*100,table.C,(table.C/C_sum)*100 
   from table , (SELECT SUM(A) A_sum,SUM(B) B_sum,SUM(C) C_sum FROM table) as t
```

or you can use this stored procedure :

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
     BEGIN

        DECLARE sum int(3);
        select sum(score) into sum from game_action;
        select *, (score/sum)*100 as pourcentage from game_action;
     END
```

and in your application you use CALL `proc`()